# Unity, Stop Moving Player when he hits obstacle or bounds

Tags: unity-game-engine

I implementing moving system, with using `MoveTowards`. Ive got couple `Collider2D` obstacles that should not by overlap by my object.

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (playerType == PLAYER_TYPE.PLAYER_ONE)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            CheckIfAbleThenMove(gameObject.transform.position + transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            CheckIfAbleThenMove(gameObject.transform.position + (-1) * transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            CheckIfAbleThenMove(gameObject.transform.position + transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            CheckIfAbleThenMove(gameObject.transform.position + (-1) * transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    float step = moveTowardsSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, step);
}

  private void CheckIfAbleThenMove(Vector2 position)
  {
      Ray ray = new Ray(position, Vector3.zero);
      RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray);

      if (hit)
      {
          if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "obstacle")
              return;
      }

      target = position;
}
```

I cannot figure it out how to disable movement only with specific direction, that player was able to bypass the obstacle.

Comment: You would need to adjust your speed vector according to the surface you collide to. I.E. get the normal of the collided point(s). Also you should not use strings to determine types. Use `enum` instead

Comment: You must check with a raycast if your movement can be done.

Comment: @Chopi I try with raycasting by result are not quite satisfying. The player is now block via obstacle but  its very hard to bypass pressing the another direction keys (the player  is blocked ). Ive update my question

Comment: Your player can pass through objects because that's not how to properly move an object with a collider. First, attach a rigidbody object to it, secondly, don't move with `transform.position`. See duplicate for how to move it. Once you do that, player should not pass through objects